# broadleaf commerce initial setup db and static asset

Tags: spring, broadleaf-commerce

I referred
http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/core/current/getting-started
to get started with broadleaf commerce. While everything is good with installation, when i run the application as mentioned i get 2 errors. They are as below:

1. Database creation error: This error comes while starting jetty server.

> SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table
>   BLC_TRANS_ADDITNL_FIELDS drop constraint FK376DDE4B9E955B1D
>   SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found:
>   PUBLIC.BLC_TRANS_ADDITNL_FIELDS

1. Static resoure mapping error: This error comes while i load any page which has image on it. Below are the details.

> StaticAssetViewController - Unable to retrieve static asset Failed to
>   delete original file
>   'C:\user\AppData\Local\Temp\30\95\Hoppin-Hot-Sauce-Bottle---d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.jpg'
>   after copy to
>   'C:\user\AppData\Local\Temp\img\sauces\Hoppin-Hot-Sauce-Bottle---d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.jpg'

**Note:** StaticAssetView issue was resolved in BLC 3.2.

Comment: I've found to reproduce this scenario since i m not using BLC 3.2..Hope ppl r using the update version..this happens when an asset is stored in the Temp folder and you have deleted the Temp folder intentionally to free up space or memory..once u start running the application, the broadleaf configuration looks for the files in ur Temp folder which is not present..so this error will be thrown..

Comment: @Lucky as per what I remember I think I didn't clear my temp folder...are you able to reproduce this issue on BLC 3.2+ ?

Comment: no haven't checked with 3.2+..I'm using 3.0.0.GA..so will update with the issue if im moving to 3.2+ ver..

Answer (score 0):

The database error shouldn't be an issue. When the app starts it first tries to clean the DB by dropping everything. If the tables or constraints don't exist you get this error and that is fine, later on in the start up sequence it will create all these DB objects.

Comment: have you worked on broadleaf commerce? Also can you also comment about static resource mapping error?

Comment: I am just learning it now. I am having problems with the static mapping but I just found this setting you add to your runtime-properties: asset.server.file.system.path=/path/to/folder

Comment: thats nice but i guess in prod environment it will create problem.